# Qual a melhor maneira de fazer a auth de login?

Tags: javascript, angular

**AuthService**

```
login(user: User){
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.API_URL}`, {
        email: user.username,
        password: user.password
    });
}

isUserLoggedIn(){
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.API_URL}/1`);
}

logoff(){
    //this.loggedIn.next(null);
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

**LoginComponent**

```
onSubmit(){
    this.submitted = true;
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(r => {
        if(r.success){
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        }
    });
}
```

**Auth Guard**

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): any{
    return this.authService.isUserLoggedIn()
    .pipe(
        map(res => {
            if (res.isAuth){
                return true;
            }
            this.router.navigate(['/login']); 
            return false;
        })
    );
}
```

- Eu tenho um Service (`AuthService`);
- No `LoginComponent`: Envia os dados a uma `API` para fazer o login (envia-se `username` e `password`) que retorna `sucesso` se o usuário existir;
- No `Guard`: Outro serviço (`isUserLoggedIn()`) verifica se o usuário está logado e se a `sessão` ainda está viva.

Existe um outra abordagem para autenticação do usuário no Angular 4+?
Seria esta abordagem usada na maioria dos projetos?

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso algo semelhante num projecto que tenho em Angular.

Tens aqui um tutorial um pouco mais complexo, mas que simplificando faz o mesmo que o teu código.
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/11/16/angular-7-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

No meu caso a API é em PHP/Laravel e uso o package [**tymon/jwt-auth**](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)

Comment: Poderia transcrever as partes mais importantes do link na sua resposta? Veja [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/5878)